# Is it possible to show frequency and channel name at the same time on AnyTone 878UV?

Tags: ht, equipment-operation, anytone

On the AnyTone 878UV I can choose to display the frequency or the channel name or frequency (Settings->Radio Set->4 Ch.Name). But seems to me like there's enough screen real estate to be able to show both. Is there a way?

I've also looked for a way to map a PF button to switching between Channel and Frequency being displayed, but so far have had no luck.

Comment: Well, since these comments have served their purpose, I deleted them and posted an answer. And thank you, @Thomas! :-)

Comment: Did Keith's answer help you? If not, please downvote it and comment that it didn't work for you. Too bad that he didn't get the credit for that, but that's still possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting this answer —by someone else— below. I'm *assuming* that it's a good one.

> You CAN assign a button to switch between Name and Frequency.
>
> Menu/Settings/Radio Set/(choose key like PF3 Long Press)/Ch.Name — When pressed, it will alternate between Frequency and Name on the display.

---

Per Thomas's comment, this required a firmware update to v. 1.21 to work.

Comment: Yes! With the caveat that the firmware I had at the time (1.17) did not support it. I just updated to 1.21 and now it is possible to choose Ch.Name for PF1 keys.

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge, both of your features are not implemented.

You can choose either name or frequency in "channel mode" and assign a key to switch between channel and VFO mode.

Comment: Hello Burn, and welcome to this site! :-)